# Get actual height of td

Tags: jquery, html

I want to   actual height of td
 I have table

```
<table>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td class="equationStart" style="padding: 8px 0">
                12121212121                            
             </td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="equationStart" style="padding: 8px 0">
                323232
                323232
               </td>
             </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

And jquery code

```
$(".equationStart").each(function (index, domElement) {
            console.log($(domElement).css("height"));
}
```

And i have in console.log()-0px

Answer (score 2):

Below is the right code:

```
$(".equationStart").each(function (index, domElement) {
    console.log($(domElement).height());
}
```

What you did there is that you asked jQuery to get `td`'s CSS height which I believe you didn't specified, that's why it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try .outerHeight() ?

```
$(".equationStart").each(function (index, domElement) {
       console.log($(domElement).outerHeight());
}
```

.outerHeight()  compute height including padding, border, and optionally margin.

Answer (score 0):

the answer you have suggested is already correct. just had to close bracket correctly

See the JS Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/8vmhdhfk/

```
$(".equationStart").each(function (index, domElement) {
        debugger;
        alert($(domElement).css("height"));
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this the code you need .. you just need to use `.outerHeight(true)`

```
$(".equationStart").each(function () {
    alert($(this).outerHeight(true));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/zjjvru03/1/)